# Typescript: Override superclass method without needing to know superclass method signature

Tags: typescript, methods, arguments, overriding, subclass

Here's how I would reliably override a method in vanilla JS without caring about names or number of arguments, or the return value:

```js
import EventEmitter from 'events'

// console.log event + arguments every time this emitter emits anything.
// Just an example.  
class LogEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  emit(...args) {
    console.log('emit', ...args)
    return super.emit(...args)
  }
}
```

But in TypeScript, I hear complaints:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

class LogEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  emit(...args) {                // Rest Parameter 'args' implicitly has an any[] type
    console.log('emit', ...args)
    return super.emit(...args)  // Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to tell TypeScript that this is ok. I don't want to know anything about the signature of the method I'm overriding, just print whatever arguments you're passed. Means I don't have to update my signature if/when the superclass signature changes, and ideally I would have one way to type this that would work for all methods I override, with maybe an exception of telling it which method name to copy the signature from.

Something like:

> The type of `...args` should be whatever the `Parameters` are to `super.emit`

But my newbie attempt at this isn't valid syntax:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

class LogEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  emit(...args: Parameters<super.emit>) {  // 'super' can only be referenced in members of derived classes or object literal expressions.
    console.log('emit', ...args)
    return super.emit(...args)
  }
}
```

My workaround is to `any` the required first argument:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

class LogEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  emit(type: any, ...args: any[]) {
    console.log('emit', type, ...args)
    return super.emit(type, ...args)
  }
}
```

But I think this is more like patching symptoms, since now this class reports a less accurate signature. I feel like there's a better solution that gives **the correct signature for `emit` automatically without me having to copy it from `super.emit`.**

How can I type this perfectly without having to know *anything* about the signature of `super.emit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Typescript does not (as of TS4.1) [contextually type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) subclass members by the analogous members in super classes (or implemented interfaces).  There are a bunch of similar GitHub issues, but I think the canonical one for this particular situation is [microsoft/TypeScript#23911](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911).  For now, all you can do is "patch symptoms":

As a workaround, if you want to refer to the super class, you will need to do so explicitly by name (`EventEmitter`) and not by `super`, and you can use a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to get the `emit` method:

```
class LogEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  emit(...args: Parameters<EventEmitter['emit']>) {
    console.log('emit', ...args)
    return super.emit(...args)
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQG4FMB2NkmDGdKOAXzgDMoIQ4BydDbAZ1oChWBjAGwEMmm4AGQgBzXPkLF0AD0KYAJgLRYceAkUSs4cdGoAUAOiM8oIpgC44ABRM8Q6SUwA8y7OPVQA2vTW0AugB8AJSa2tocEJhMEFzoBlyiej74tAA0cEYGJmZBWmFQDgCuUJhwTIVgRAa6+IbGpky52mSsJEA)

Comment: Great. This worked.

Do you know if there's any difference between `Parameters<EventEmitter['emit']>` and `Parameters<typeof EventEmitter.prototype.emit>`, as given in this similar answer by @willis https://stackoverflow.com/a/66020642/62851?

Comment: I noticed that if I used a different `EventEmitter` library (`eventemitter3`), it'd report two different resulting signatures depending on which option I used: `EventEmitter['emit']` gives `emit(event: string | symbol, ...args: any[])` but `typeof EventEmitter.prototype.emit` gives something different: `emit(event: any, ...args: any[])`??

With node's `EventEmitter`, they were the same signature (first option).

Maybe there's something wrong with `eventemitter3`'s typings, but I'm curious why there's any difference at all?

Comment: There would not normally be a difference, assuming that `EventEmitter.prototype` has type `EventEmitter` (which it does in TypeScript, despite that not really being accurate), then `typeof EventEmitter.prototype.emit` should be the same type as `EventEmitter['emit']`.  If you're actually seeing differences, then presumably it has something to do with the library typings, but without seeing it in front of me I wouldn't be able to say anything definitive.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof fn` lets you get the type of a function, so `Parameters<typeof EventEmitter.prototype.emit>` should get things working.